# What is the recommended way to store post comments in Firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am building an app using Firebase, based on a classic blog style structure.

The app will have `properties` (like posts), `users` and `comments` (made on each of the properties).

Is it best to store the `comments` under each `property`, or under its own path /comments with an id to the property?

**Here's the structure I have so far:**

[image]

In the above image, I began storing comments as their own path /comments, but I'm wondering if this is the best idea? If so, would I set the comment key to be the same as the property key?

I'm very much still trying to get my head around structuring a flat DB like this, coming from a more RDBM system / experience.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: I was looking for something similar and i found yours. I Think this should help [Firebase - users comment on things
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731614/firebase-users-comment-on-things?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you don't always have to access the properties for each comment then yeah I would have them separate like what you have above where the key for both is the same (as long as it is an exact 1-1 mapping).

If every time you need to access a comment you need its properties then you could combine them into a single node.

Comment: It would be nice to show comments on each property, but also to show each comment a particular user has made on their own dashboard, away from a property. How would I structure it to account for this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first, but for the second I'd create another node called userComments and store the user id followed by the comment id in a sub object.