# Firebase - users comment on things

Tags: android, firebase

I am building an android app that allows users to comment on each song on the billboard top 100 (I parsed that info from a JSON fie). How would I go about storing the comments (preferably using Firebase) and displaying and refreshing them after a new comment is made?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming there is a unique ID for each song. So for each song what you can do is-

1. Get the song reference

   ```
   private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

   mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

   mSongRef = mDatabase.child("SongID");
   ```
2. Whenever someone comment on a song, push() the object of Comment class as child node of that song:

   ```
   String commentKey = mSongRef.push().getKey();
   mSongRef.child(commentKey).setValue(comment);
   ```
3. Now to fetch the newly added comment

   ```
   mSongRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);

       Log.d(TAG, "Comment: " + comment.getCommentText() + ", User: " + comment.getUsername());
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
   // Failed to read value
       Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
   }});
   ```
4. Now that you have recent data, you can add the comment to your list and update recycler/list view.

Comment: So this would work perfectly for me if I was storing my songs in a database. However, I just have a JSON file with 100 songs on it and I am parsing that and displaying each one as a song object using Async Task. I can click on each song object and it will lead to a page that contains comments by users of the app. So is there some way I could go about it with this set of circumstances?

Comment: No, I am not suggesting to store songs in firebase database. I am saying to store just the songID associated with each song to be stored as node, under which comments will be stored for that song as children. So when the user click on a song..play that song from local storage or wherever you have stored and fetch comments from firebase.